# Change cell format but not number size?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When cells are in percentage format, you may have one that is 5.97% and another 87.2%. When you change format to number you get 0.0597 and 0.872. Is there a way to change format to number but not scale? e.g 5.97% would go do 5.97? It seems simple but i can't find a way to do it in the same cell. Thanks for any help offered! :)

**Edit:** I know you can try things like LEFT(LEN()) or reformat and *100 but this becomes annoying if the cell values are produced by formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format - cell

In alignment untick wrap text

In number - custom type 0.00 then CTRL+j then % and you should be good!

Comment: Golden! nice one, what does this actually do though?

Comment: @IIJHFII what it is doing is moving the `%` down one line so that if your cell is large enough you would still see it, but it the cell is only showing one line then it is cut off on the bottom.  `Ctrl +j` adds a line break.